# wxpython-phoenix requires python framework on osx/ipython/pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pycharm, wxpython

Running the sample hello-world code offered on [wxpython-phoenix website](https://wxpython.org/pages/overview/) throws a known error on osx. Hints at possible solutions can be found [here](https://github.com/facelessuser/rummage/issues/127), and [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonVirtualenvOnMac), but none seem to work with ipython and pycharm.

**QUESTION: How to work around this known error, using ipython from within pycharm?**

**Set up:**

OSX 10.12.5 Sierra
ipython 3.7.1 in a conda venv
pycharm CE 2018.3
(also fails from command line, and from jupyter notebook)

**code ran**: (from wxpython getting started page)

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
frm = wx.Frame(None, title="Hello World")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

**error message**

```
This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a
Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in
on the main display of your Mac.
```

**full traceback**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5af94fb54276> in <module>
      3 
      4 # Next, create an application object.
----> 5 app = wx.App()
      6 
      7 # Then a frame.

~/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wx/core.py in __init__(self, redirect, filename, useBestVisual, clearSigInt)
   2100                 # TODO: more description is needed for wxMSW...
   2101 
-> 2102             raise SystemExit(msg)
   2103 
   2104         # This has to be done before OnInit

SystemExit: This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a
Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in
on the main display of your Mac.
```

Note: This question is similar to:
- [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686592/wxpython-and-pycharm-on-mac) one which was for python2.7, but did not receive an answer
- [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531006/wxpython-this-program-needs-access-to-the-screen) one which offers outdated fixes for regular python, outside of pycharm
Other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362024/ipython-on-wxpython), are obsolete for the new release of wxpython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using conda environments you need to install the `python.app` package and then use `pythonw` to run applications that use wxPython.

On osx, the command line is: (as shown [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python.app))

`conda install -c anaconda python.app`

You will see the following message; confirm to proceed.

> ```
> The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:
>
>     python.app: 2-py37_9 --> 2-py37_9 anaconda
> ```

With **pycharm**, it is necessary to change the project interpreter:

--> go to:

```
preferences
  project interpreter
    add interpreter
      conda environment
        anaconda (or anaconda3)
          bin
            pythonw 
select pythonw
apply
ok
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well, appreciated. If you like, I'll create a pull request to include this in the readme, or documentation.